# How to select a single line from a leafletjs polyline when clicked?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, polyline

I have a leaflet map (using Vue and vue2-leaflet) with many predefined nodes and connections between them (stored in a neo4j database). When the user clicks on a node (@mouseup, actually), all its connections are shown as a polyline. I want to be able to click on any of these connections on the map (the lines) and do stuff with it, like delete for example (there would be a popup or something with actions, but that's not important here).

The problem I'm having is that the click event doesn't record the connection ID (or anything that would identify which connection was in fact clicked). I could of course create one polyline for each connection, but I suspect the problem would persist, and it's not a really solution in my case, as I don't know how many connections each node has, and `v-for` doesn't seem to work with polylines (at least I wasn't able to make it work).

This is the nodes markers code:

```
<l-marker v-for="mapNode in MapStore.mapNodes"
  @mouseup="nodeClick($event, mapNode.index)"
  :lat-lng="[mapNode.latLng.lat, mapNode.latLng.lng]"
  :key="mapNode.index"
</l-marker>
```

... and this is the polyline code:

```
<l-polyline
  @mouseup="connectionClick($event)"
  :lat-lngs="MapStore.selectedConnections.latlngs"
/>
```

The `nodeClick` function populates the `MapStore.selectedConnections` correctly as the polylines are shown as expected.

The problem is that I don't see anything being passed to the `connectionClick` function that would identify which connection was clicked, so that I could work with it.

Is that even possible?

Comment: If I do something like ```<l-polyline v-for="connection in MapStore.selectedConnections"
          @mouseup="connectionClick($event)"
          :key="MapStore.selectedConnections.ids[connection]"
          :lat-lngs="MapStore.selectedConnections.latlngs[connection]" />``` the polylines are not shown at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out I was wrong and `v-for` works (there was something wrong with my code, I think, but I'm not sure what).

My solution is:

```
<l-polyline v-for="connection in MapStore.selectedConnections.latlngs"
  @mouseup="connectionClick($event, connection)"
  :lat-lngs="connection" />
```

This way it iterates through the connections, generates a separate polyline for each and passes to the `connectionClick` function the `latlngs` of the clicked connection.